# Are there good alternative Scheme syntaxes?

Tags: syntax, scheme

I imagine Scheme (and perhaps Lisp) could be made more `user friendly' by using a different syntax. For example, instead of nested S-expressions with ugly parentheses, one could devise some kind of syntax closer to some of the more widely used languages (e.g. Java-like without needing to define classes).

It's not necessarily a bad thing if it's more verbose. For example, the syntax may require line separators and commas in the places where many people will expect them, and expect explicit return statements. Also, it doesn't seem that difficult to allow some operators to be used infix style (just obey the generally accepted operator preference rules).

And if it doesn't make things too messy, the syntax could even be backwards-compatible, so that in any place where an expression is expected, a normal S-expression between parentheses can be used.

What are your opinions and ideas about this? And does anything like this exist? (I expect it does, but "Scheme" is a worthless google term, I can't find anything!)

Comment: Pro tip: Google for `Scheme language` :)

Comment: No, I don't think anybody wants this.

Comment: I propose an alternative JavaScript syntax that replaces ugly C-style code with elegant S-expressions.

Answer (score 9):

Originally, Lisp was planned to use a syntax called M-Expressions, with S-Expressions being only a transitional solution for easier compiler building. When M-Expressions were ready to be introduces, the programmers who had already taken on Lisp just stayed with what they had become accustomed to, and M-Expressions never caught on.

There is an infix notation in Guile, but it's rarely used. A good Lisp programmer doesn't even see the parens anymore, and prefix notation does have its merits...

Comment: Totally agree about not seeing the parens. The key is using an editor with a Lisp mode. Then what you see is indentation. Which is the end to which parens are just the means.

Racket (formerly PLT Scheme) also has some infix: (a . f . b) ==> (f a b). You'll see this used sometimes for contracts: (in . -> . out) instead of (-> in out). But not always. And not for much else. Because prefix does have its merits.

Answer (score 8):

I think "sweet expressions" might be one of the more thoughtful approaches to getting rid of the parentheses in Lisp. It apparently even supports macros.

http://www.dwheeler.com/readable/sweet-expressions.html

However, I think most people eventually get over the parentheses or use another language.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at "sweet-expressions", which provides a set of additional abbreviations for traditional s-expressions.  They add syntactically-relevant indentation, a way to do infix, and traditional function calls like f(x).  Unlike nearly all past efforts to make Lisps readable, sweet-expressions are backwards-compatible (you can freely mix well-formatted s-expressions and sweet-expressions), generic, and homoiconic.

Sweet-expressions were developed on http://readable.sourceforge.net and there is a sample implementation.

For Scheme there is a SRFI for sweet-expresssions: http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-110/

Comment: Besides sweet-expressions themselves, http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-110/srfi-110.html#comparisons surveys a lot of alternative efforts.

Answer (score 3):

Try [SRFI 49](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-49/srfi-49.html) for size. :-P

(Seriously, though, as Rafe commented, "I don't think anybody wants this".)

Answer (score 2):

Some people consider Python to be a kind of Scheme with infix notation for operators, algebraic notation for functions and which uses a more "java-like" syntax for representing the language. I don't agree with that assessment, but I can see where the idea comes from.

The big problem with changing the notation for Scheme is that macros become very hard to write (to see how hard, take a look at the Nimrod language or Boo). Instead of working directly with the code as lists, you have to parse the input language first. This usually involves constructing an AST (abstract syntax tree) for the language from the input. When working directly with Scheme, this is unnecessary.

However, you might check out the SIX expression syntax in Gambit Scheme. There's a nice set of slides here which contains a discussion of this:

http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~gambit/Gambit-inside-out.pdf

But don't tell anyone about it! (The inside joke is that someone suggests writing a Lisp without parentheses and with infix notation about once a day, and someone announces an implementation about once a month.)

Comment: People consider Python to be a kind of Scheme in the sense of being a small language with first-class functions and a single namespace ("Lisp-1") - BUT without macros.

Answer (score 1):

There are some languages that do exactly that. For instance: [Dylan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dylan_programming_language).